# Qual o erro no meu código? Linguagem C Iniciante

Tags: c

> ##### Atividade:
>
> Foi  realizada  uma  pesquisa  entre  2000  habitantes  de  uma  cidade.  De  cada  habitante  foram coletados  os  dados:  idade,  sexo,  renda  familiar  e  número  de  filhos.  Faça  um algoritmo que  leia  esses dados. Calcule e mostre a média da renda familiar, a maior idade do grupo e a quantidade de mulheres com mais de dois filhos e com renda familiar inferior a R$ 600.00.

Este é o meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    int idade[5];
    char sexo[5];
    float rendaFamiliar[5];
    int numFilhos[5];
    float mediaRenda = 0;
    float rendaAtvar = 0;
    int maiorIdade = 0;
    int qntMulheres = 0;
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
        printf("Digite a idade: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &idade[i]);
        printf("\nDigite o sexo: ");
        scanf("%s%*c", &sexo[i]);
        printf("\nDigite a renda familiar: ");
        scanf("%f%*c", &rendaFamiliar[i]);
        printf("\nDigite o número de filhos: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &numFilhos[i]);
        rendaAtvar = rendaAtvar + rendaFamiliar[i];
        if(idade[i] > maiorIdade){
            maiorIdade = idade[i];
        }
        if(sexo[i] == 'f' && numFilhos[i] > 2 && rendaFamiliar[i] < 600){
            qntMulheres++;
        }
    }
    
    mediaRenda = rendaAtvar/5;
    
    printf("\n\nA média de renda familiar é R$ %.2f\nA pessoa mais velha do grupo tem %d anos\n%d mulheres tem mais de 2 filhos e uma renda familiar inferior à R$ 600,00", &mediaRenda, &maiorIdade, &qntMulheres);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

O programa fica assim depois que eu insiro alguns dados de teste
[[image: Imagem mostrando o output do programa]
<sup>clique para visualizar em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9CG.png)

Comment: Criei vetores de 5 posições por que não ia testar 2000 né

Comment: Em seu código o que exatamente esta tendo dificuldades? qual sua interpretação da solução para o enunciado.Sua postagem aparenta não ser uma orientação para finaliza-lo pq só possui a atividade e o código e não apresenta suas duvidas sua dificuldade desse modo podera ter ajuda do que apenas postar código e a atividade.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O erro está na linha de código do printf que exibe todos os resultados.O erro está no uso do operador "&" . Esse operador é usado como um ponteiro para uma posição da memória onde vai ser armazenado o valor da variável.No caso, colocando esse "&" você está acessando o endereço da variável e não o valor dela em si. Eu tirei esse operador e o código funcionou normalmente[image: Print da operação correta]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Poxa, muitíssimo obrigada.

Comment: Não sei pk deram downvote, se vc entendeu minha pergunta e sua resposta resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Haters, talvez ? Kkkk. Mas talvez seja algum erro conceitual, mas sinceramente eu revisei e não vi nada de errado no que eu escrevi. Inclusive eu recomendo você ler um pouco de ponteiros e sobre esse operador "&", tem mais informações a respeito. No mais, bons estudos. Outra coisa : precisa melhorar a suas próximas perguntas, pra não ficar confuso de entender.